# forgiving people on the first night of Pesach

Tags: minhag, passover, shema, forgiving-mechilah

According to the Ezras Torah Luach, we only say the bracha of המפיל and the Shema itself for Kriat Shema al Hamita, skipping the rest, because Pesach is leil shimurim, when we don't need extra prayers for protection.

What about the first paragraph (at least in Nusach Artscroll), which involves forgiving anyone who accidentally harmed us?  Why should this be less important on Pesach than any other day?

Comment: I understood that first paragraph to be said on Pesach night as well. Maybe that goes without saying; of the proper Krias Shema, only Hamapil and Shema is said.